# Cython random number seeds

Tags: python, random, numbers, cython

how do i get more random seed? i'm only getting ~32k random numbers...

```
In [3]:

%load_ext cythonmagic
In [4]:

%%cython
from libc.stdlib cimport rand, srand, RAND_MAX

cpdef test():
    return RAND_MAX
In [5]:

test()
Out[5]:
32767
```

Comment: If your question is "How can I use `rand` to generate random numbers larger than `RAND_MAX`?", could you instead use Python's `random.randint`? You can use it to generate integers of any size.

Comment: i certainly could. but this random function needs to be called million Xs.

Comment: How about making multiple calls to `rand` and compositing them together? `(rand() >> (2**15)) + rand()` ought to return a random integer between 0 and (`RAND_MAX`^2).

Comment: In [20]: %timeit np.random.RandomState(1).rand(100000, 240)
1 loops, best of 3: 366 ms per loop
In [18]: %timeit randoms()
1 loops, best of 3: 314 ms per loop

Comment: figured it's only 50 ms difference. so i just pre-generate the numbers before the loop.